# d3 linear scale with strange output values

Tags: d3.js

Recently I have began exploring D3 and I'm having some issues with scales.

I'm in a earlier stages of a simple bar chart and my `yScale` is outputting some stranges values.

I've notice that this doesn't happen if I simple define the domain like `.domain([0, 8000])` which is not very dynamic…

Here's the link for the csv file:

[Google Transparency Report: User data requests](http://www.visualizing.org/datasets/google-transparency-report-user-data-requests)

And here's the code:

```
    var dataset;

    var w = 500;
    var h = 300;

    var svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h);

    d3.csv("google-user-data-requests.csv", function(data) {
        dataset = data;
        generateVis();
    });

    var generateVis = function () {

        var barValue = function(d) {
            return d["User Data Requests"];
        };

        var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .domain(d3.range(dataset.length))
            .rangeRoundBands([0, w], 0.05);

        var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, barValue)])
            .range([0, h]);

        var bars = svg.selectAll("rect")
            .data(dataset)
            .enter()
            .append("rect")

        var barsAttr = bars 
            .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                return xScale(i);
            })
            .attr("y", function(d) {
                return h - yScale(barValue(d));
            })
            .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand())
            .attr("height", function(d) {
                return yScale(barValue(d));
            });
    };
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have any way you could show us what you get, and what you actually expected?

Comment: @AndyClifton Well, I already got the answer bellow. I needed to parse my csv data before trying to do anything with it. Tks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is convert your strings to numbers, i.e.

```
d3.csv("google-user-data-requests.csv", function(data) {
    dataset = data;
    dataset.forEach(function(d) {
      d['User Data Requests'] = +d['User Data Requests'];
    });
    generateVis();
});
```

You probably also want to parse the dates and format them as such.